# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/androidx.appcompat_appcompat.version'

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm confused with this error.

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/androidx.appcompat_appcompat.version'
```

here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ciangproduction.sestyc"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version'
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

    implementation(name: 'sinch-android-rtc', version: '+', ext: 'aar')

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'

    //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2-native'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.2.0'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I've tried everything with similar error code such as excluding it with packagingOptions. But it still show the same error code. everything is fine until i tried to change the dependencies value to the latest one.(sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to exclude the duplicate dependency (one must stay left):

```
dependencies {
    implementation ("com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.2.0") {
        exclude group: "androidx.appcompat", module: "appcompat"
    }
}
```

`ucrop` also has `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0` ...

would migrate to `androidx` and exclude all transitive dependencies and  declare them instead.

see the [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Comment: Possibly the answer, the error occurred after i added this "com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.2.0" library. I’ll check it later. Thanks for your solution